# Laravel, simplifying relationships: multiple sortable models

Tags: php, sorting, laravel, orm, eloquent

As I was working on a Laravel project I noticed a recurring pattern in my models:

- `Model A` hasMany `Model B`
- `Model B` can optionally be hidden
- `Model B` can optionally be sorted

Examples:

A gallery has pictures. You can choose not to display a picture or you can choose to sort them.

A "view our team" page. You can choose not to display certain employees or you can choose to sort them.

A slider on the home page. You can choose not to display certain images or you can choose to sort them.

I've been implementing all of these as follows:

```
class ModelA extends Model {
    function modelBs() {
        $this->hasMany('modelB');
    }
}

class modelB extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['visible', 'order'];
    function modelA() {
        $this->belongsTo('modelA');
    }
}
```

I'm also repeatedly re-implementing (copying/pasting) the code for displaying these in blade templates:

```
@foreach( $modelA->modelBs()->sortBy('order') as $modelB )
    @if( $modelB->visible )
        <li>{{ $modelB->output() }}</li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

And in the admin panel I have to repeatedly re-implement (copy/paste) the the jQuery-UI sortable widget for modifying the order, serializing your decision, and submitting it to the server then saving this order (via updating every `Model B`'s order appropriately)

It's getting out of hand, and I remembered the adage from Laracasts:

> If you find yourself using copy and paste, there's probably a better way to do it

As I tried to think of a better solution, this is the first relationship that I imagined:

- `Model A` hasMany `SortThing`
- `SortThing` morphsTo `sortable`
- `Model B` hasOne `sortable`

This way I know that **any** `SortThing` can be sorted or hidden, and a `SortThing` can reference any sortable object (pictures, employees, slider panels, etc)

The problem is doing this doesn't really make my code any more DRY:

```
class ModelA extends Model {
    function modelBs() {
        $this->hasMany('SortThing');
    }
}

class modelB extends Model {
    function sortable() {
        $this->morphsOne('SortThing', 'sortable');
    }
}

class SortThing extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['visible', 'order'];
    function sortable() {
        $this->morphTo();
    }
}

@foreach( $modelA->modelBs()->sortBy('order') as $modelB )
    @if( $modelB->visible )
        <li>{{ $modelB->sortable->output() }}</li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I've added an extra class and necessitated the `sortable->` in my output and I'm still copying/pasting code.

Any advice on how to clean up my code would be appreciated. Still a bit of a Laravel newb.

Bonus points if the resulting relationship doesn't require me to update 18 database rows when objects are re-ordered as this could potentially lead to some ugly overhead as the lists get really long.

#### Update

Attempting @gpopoteur's answer below (after fixing the typo in his declaration of the `renderItems` function) I got the following error:

```
[2015-03-24 13:08:52] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'App\Slider and App\HasSortableItemsTrait define the same property ($sortItemClass) in the composition of App\Slider. However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible. Class was composed' in /var/www/example.com/app/Slider.php:26
```

Slider.php looks like so:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Slider extends Model {

    use HasSortableItemsTrait;

    protected $sortItemClass = 'App\SliderPanel';

    //
    public function sliderable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function panels() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SliderPanel');
    }

    public function output() {
        $panels = $this->panels();
        return "Test?";

    }

} // Line 26
```

and HasSortableItemsTrait.php looks like so:

```
<?php namespace App;

trait HasSortableItemsTrait {

    protected $sortItemClass; // Also tried $sortItemClass = ''; and $sortItemClass = null;

    public function items() {
        $this->hasMany($this->sortItemClass)->sortyBy('order')->where('visible', '=', true);
    }

    public function renderItems($htmlTag = '<li>:item</li>') {
        $render = '';
        foreach( $this->items() as $item ){
            $render .= str_replace($item->render(), ':item', $htmlTag);
        }

        return $render;
    }

}
```

#### Update 2

I've figured out that commenting out the following line fixes my issue:

```
protected $sortItemClass;
```

Of course I still have to make sure anything using the trait defines `$sortItemClass` or it will fail when calling `items()`

Now I'm getting a new error:

```
[2015-03-24 13:34:50] production.ERROR: exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortBy()' in /var/www/example.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:1992
```

I double-checked the Laravel docs and I'm like 90% sure that `sortBy` should be a valid method on query builders...

Comment: Plus for searching for **a better way**, however using polymorphic relations for this is the last thing I would think of and never use in such case ;) The better way here would be abstracting your JS sorting logic, so you can simply reuse it, and the same goes for your backend code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding everything in a trait, and then just `use SortableTrait;` on your Model. And then setting the class as a `protected` attribute of the other Sortable items that it has many.

#### !!! Code below is not tested !!!

Lets define a trait for the Class that has sortable Items.

```
    trait HasSortableItemsTrait {

        // define this in your class
        // protected $sortItemClass

        public function items() {
            $this->hasMany($sortItemClass)->orderBy('order');
        }

        public function renderItems($htmlTag = '<li>:item</li>']) {
            return $this->items->map(function($item) use ($htmlTag) {
                if( $item->visible ){
                    return str_replace($item->render(), ':item', $htmlTag);
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Another trait to use on the items that are sortable.

```
    trait IsSortableTrait {

        // define this in your class
        // protected $sortItemParent

        function items() {
            $this->belongsTo($sortItemParent);
        }

        function render(){
            return $this->output();
        }

    }
```

Lets do an example with a Gallery that has Sortable Photos. This is how the `App\Gallery` should look like:

```
    class Gallery extends Model {
        use HasSortableItemsTrait;

        protected $sortItemClass = 'App\Photo';
    }
```

And this is how the `App\Photo` class would look like:

```
    class Photo extends Model {
        use IsSortableTrait;

        protected $sortItemParent = 'App\Gallery';
    }
```

Then you just need to fetch the Item that has many sortable items, in this case the gallery.

```
    $gallery = Gallery::find(1);
```

And in the view you just need to call the  `renderItems()` method of the view.

```
    {{ $gallery->renderItems() }}
```

I made the `renderItems` method be able to receive how you want to wrap what the `$item->render()` will be giving as output. For example, between `<p></p>` you just have to call the method like this:

```
    {{ $gallery->renderItems('<p>:item</p>') }}
```

Comment: Is there a good "best practice" for organizing traits in Laravel? As of Laravel 5 it seems like models go directly in the `/app` directory, controllers go in `/app/Http/Controllers`, etc. However when I grep for "trait" I only find unit tests or things in the `/vendor` folder.

Comment: Dumped `HasSortableItemTrait.php` into the `/app` directory for now and got an error -- updating my question in case you can help with this.

Comment: @stevendesu I made a typo inside the foreach that is in `HasSortableItemsTrait`, just edited the Trait, please review it. Also the `SliderPanel ` should use the second trait that I added, the `use IsSortableTrait;`

Comment: There were a couple other issues to fix (you have a stray `]` in your definition of `renderItems()` and you need to replace `$sortItemClass` with `$this->sortItemClass` in `items()`) although commenting out the `$sortItemClass` in the trait did fix the first issue. Now I've got a second problem: it says that `sortBy` is undefined on Builder...

Comment: @stevendesu the `sortBy()` method works in an `Collection` object, in the `Builder` class you must use `orderBy()` to get the desired result. Just updated the Trait with this.

Comment: Working now! Thank you. The only improvement I'm going to try and make in my official version will be the addition of a `hasManySortable()` method (mimicking the functionality of `hasMany`) so that I can attach multiple sortable models to a single one (as it's written a model can only have one list of sortable items)

Comment: @stevendesu glad that it helped, made an improvement in the `renderItems()` method of the `HasSortableItemsTrait`, changed the foreach with the Collection `map()` functional method, looks cleaner now.